# Remote Desktop Freezing and giving a weird error

Tags: macos, windows-8, remote-desktop

So for the last few days, I've been using windows remote desktop from my macbook to connect to my PC upstairs to do work. But the last few days I've been having issues with the connection freezing randomly every few seconds.

Then tonight I just had the session randomly close while I was editing a html file. I closed like I had hit the "Close session button", that is to say, it didn't crash but acted as if I had closed the session.

I tried re-connecting, but as soon as it connected the session closed again. After trying a few more times, it gave me a weird white screen with rounded edges, and the next time I tried connecting again, it said "The server denied the logon with reason: 3489660951".

I searched around a bit, but I could;t find anyone with a similar error, I'm wondering if I somehow got a virus on my remote machine and it's causing this.

My operating system on my remote PC is Windows 8.1 with the latest updates, and my Macbook is OSX 10.9.5

Comment: Maybe try a different client?  Maybe flakey network?

Comment: Have you got Windows Updates to install? Have they completed successfully? have you rebooted since installing them? Googling your error message comes up with a few who have had the same and Windows Updates seems to grop up...

Answer (score 0):

You can attempt more troubleshooting by running an antivirus scan on the remote machine. You could also create a test machine with another Windows box. On top of that you can change the listening port of RDP and see if your issue only happens on the default port 3389. Other than that maybe a network device such as a firewall is interfering.

Comment: Good suggestions, I've been planning on running a virus scan today to be sure. I know it isn't the firewall, as the one on my PC is configure to allow RDP, and we don't have a network firewall that blocks any internal traffic.

Answer (score 0):

You could look into the eventvwr.msc on Windows both Application and System. The same on Mac though I don't know where you can find them there.